# unable to upload StructureDefinitions when Validation-Requests-Enabled (DSTU3)

Tags: hapi-fhir

I am experimenting with the automatic validation feature of HAPI-Fhir Server. I am using the hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter running in a docker container. For compatibility reasons I am forced to stick at DSTU3 for the moment. My observed behavior is the following:

If request-validation is off (controlled via Env variable API_FHIR_VALIDATION_REQUESTSENABLED unset) I can upload ValueSet and StructureDefinition resources. When uploading eg. Patient or Observation resources, I can use the .../$validate REST call to validate the resources. Works as expected.

If request-validation is on (HAPI_FHIR_VALIDATION_REQUESTSENABLED set to true) then uploading of StructureDefinitions which refer to ValueSet resources being present (by binding.valueSetReference) fail with messages like `This context is for FHIR version "DSTU3" but the class "org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.ValueSet" is for version "R4"`. Validation of resources like Patient or Observation being uploaded works as expected. These resources are marked with a reference to my own StructureDefinitions and are validated against them. Resources with errors will not be persisted.

My current workaround is to disable validation, upload ValueSet and StructureDefinition resources. After a restart with HAPI_FHIR_VALIDATION_REQUESTSENABLED=true the server works as expected and correctly validates all resources being uploaded.

Is there a way to either avoid the errors above or prevent StructureDefinition or ValueSet resources from validation for an individual upload-request?

Every help will be appreciated.
-wolfgang